# Is there any way of visually interpreting Weierstrass M test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Can anyone suggest me some way to visualize Weierstrass M test of uniform convergence of a series of functions?

**Statement:**

**Suppose ${f_n}$ is a sequence of functions such that $\exists$ a sequence $(M_n)$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n \forall x$ and $\forall n \in \Bbb N$.If $\sum M_n$ converges then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly.**

I want to visualize graphically what is going on.

Comment: This is not a visual argument, but the following thought process seems fairly clear to me. If $f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$, then for any $x$ we have $| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x) | = |\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty f_i(x) | \leq \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty | f_i(x) | \leq \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty M_i$. This gives us a bound on $| f(x) - \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x) |$ which does not depend on $x$.

Comment: That is nice.But I am still in search of a visual argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one visualisation (See the statement of [Weierstrass M test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)):

- Put $S_n = 2\sum_{k=1}^n M_k$, $S = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} M_k$, and draw the lines $y = S_n$ for each $n$. (Think of a [rainbow cake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_cookie) of finite thickness $S$ but infinitely many layers.)
- Let the *$n$th layer* be the plane between the lines $y=S_{n-1}$ and $y=S_n$. Put $Z_n = S_n - M_n$ for each $n$ and draw a dotted line $y=Z_n$ for each $n$. (The idea is that for each $n$ we can shift the $x$-axis to the $n$th dotted line, and the $n$th layer represents ‘$0 \pm M_n$’.)
- If for all $n$, you can plot $y=|f_n(x)|+Z_n$ within the $n$th layer then the M test is passed: you can add all of the $f_n$ together and the sum will converge.

Uniform convergence is (*I think*) guaranteed because the layers are the same thickness across the entire domain. For pointwise convergence, the layer thicknesses could vary with $x$, and so you would need to accumulate more layers (increase $n$) to guarantee that the total thickness is under control.

Comment: what is the guarantee of uniformity?

Comment: Can someone provide a diagram?